# Jquery: How to traverse dom to slideToggle groups of tab elements

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have a groups of tab-links and tab content panes on the same page, each with a varying number of tabs.

```
<div class="tab-content-group1">
  <div class="tabs-group">
    <a class="tab1">Tab 1</a>
    <a class="tab2">Tab 2</a>
    <a class="tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane-group">
    <div class="tab-pane1">Tab Content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane2">Tab Content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane3">Tab Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content-group2">
  <div class="tabs-group">
    <a class="tab4">Tab 4</a>
    <a class="tab5">Tab 5</a>
    <a class="tab6">Tab 6</a>
    <a class="tab7">Tab 7</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane-group">
    <div class="tab-pane4">Tab Content 4</div>
    <div class="tab-pane5">Tab Content 5</div>
    <div class="tab-pane6">Tab Content 6</div>
    <div class="tab-pane7">Tab Content 7</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content-group3">
  <div class="tabs-group">
    <a class="tab8">Tab 8</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane-group">
    <div class="tab-pane8">Tab Content 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where, in each tab group, the first tab link should slideToggle the first tab-content when clicked, the second tab link slideToggles the second content and the same for 3 and 4. This is repeated for the other tab groups.

To slideToggle the content panes when the tab is clicked, I have been using this:

```
  $(".tab1").click(function() {
    $("tab1").slideToggle("slow", function() {});
  });

  $(".tab2").click(function() {
    $("tab2").slideToggle("slow", function() {});
  });

   $(".tab3").click(function() {
    $("tab3").slideToggle("slow", function() {});
  });
```

*...etc for each tab.*

**Question 1)** Is there a more efficient way to write the code so each tab and pane doesn't need a class hard-coding everything anytime new tabs or new tab groups are added (eg. tab1, tab2, tab-pane1 etc) .

(I was thinking of something like "determine which tab is being clicked in a tab-content-group (1st, 2nd 3rd etc) then find the next tab-pane-group and slideToggle the corresdponding tab-pane that's in there (1st tab toggles first tab-pane, 2nd tab toggles second tab-pane etc) – but I have no idea how to achieve this with JQuery!)

*Please note I can't change the HTML structure.*

**Question 2)** What is the best way to get these slideToggles to behave as though part of a group that is aware of each other's toggle state to make sure any open tabs are closed when new tabs are opened.

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your HTML structure you could  use index of each `a` element to `slideToggle` `div`'s in `.tab-pane-group`

```js
$('.tab-pane-group div').hide();
$('.tabs-group a').click(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  $(this).parent().next().find('div:eq(' + i + ')').slideToggle().siblings().slideUp();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content-group1">
  <div class="tabs-group">
    <a class="tab1">Tab 1</a>
    <a class="tab2">Tab 2</a>
    <a class="tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane-group">
    <div class="tab-pane1">Tab Content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane2">Tab Content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane3">Tab Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content-group2">
  <div class="tabs-group">
    <a class="tab4">Tab 4</a>
    <a class="tab5">Tab 5</a>
    <a class="tab6">Tab 6</a>
    <a class="tab7">Tab 7</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane-group">
    <div class="tab-pane4">Tab Content 4</div>
    <div class="tab-pane5">Tab Content 5</div>
    <div class="tab-pane6">Tab Content 6</div>
    <div class="tab-pane7">Tab Content 7</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content-group3">
  <div class="tabs-group">
    <a class="tab8">Tab 8</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane-group">
    <div class="tab-pane8">Tab Content 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you also want to hide divs in other `.tab-pane-group` you can use this

```js
$('.tab-pane-group div').hide();
$('.tabs-group a').click(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  $('.tab-pane-group div').slideUp();
  $(this).parent().next().find('div:eq(' + i + ')').slideToggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content-group1">
  <div class="tabs-group">
    <a class="tab1">Tab 1</a>
    <a class="tab2">Tab 2</a>
    <a class="tab3">Tab 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane-group">
    <div class="tab-pane1">Tab Content 1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane2">Tab Content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane3">Tab Content 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content-group2">
  <div class="tabs-group">
    <a class="tab4">Tab 4</a>
    <a class="tab5">Tab 5</a>
    <a class="tab6">Tab 6</a>
    <a class="tab7">Tab 7</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane-group">
    <div class="tab-pane4">Tab Content 4</div>
    <div class="tab-pane5">Tab Content 5</div>
    <div class="tab-pane6">Tab Content 6</div>
    <div class="tab-pane7">Tab Content 7</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content-group3">
  <div class="tabs-group">
    <a class="tab8">Tab 8</a>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane-group">
    <div class="tab-pane8">Tab Content 8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Using the 'index' is exactly what I was wondering was possible, many thanks Nenad.

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1)**

Yes, you can select all tabs by `$('.tab1, .tab2, .tab3, ...')` and use `$(this)`:

```
$('.tab1, .tab2, .tab3, ...').click(function() {
    $(this).slideToggle("slow", function() {});
});
```

or select all elements, that starts with `.tab`: `$('[class^=tab]')`

**Question 2)**

Hide all tabs, and open just that which is clicked

```
var tabs = $('[class^=tab]');

tabs.click(function() {
    tabs.slideUp("slow", function() {});
    $(this).slideDown("slow", function() {});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martin – I was hoping to find a way that meant I could remove the '.tab1, .tab2 etc' so I didn't have to manually add the classes  everytime a new tab was added. Nenad's reply above has a good way of achieving this.